# Google Sheets Using Countifs & Unique Together

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying count the number of unique clients of *Payroll* service who are *Won*.

The answer as per the table below should be 4.

[image]

How can I achieve this, given that the table will be dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:C; "select A where B='Payroll' and C='Won'"; 0)))
```

[image: 9]